# How do I display the value of an option on a drop down in an output box when a button with an assigned function is clicked on?

Tags: javascript

How do I display the value of an option on a drop down in an output box when a button with an assigned function is clicked on? 
I am new to programming and don't really understand.

```
/* This function is meant to take the value of the selected option and 
  display it in the output textbox */
function scoringValue() {
  var chosenOne = document.getElementById("totalPoints").value + document.getElementById("options").value;
  document.getElementById("totalPoints").value = chosenOne;
}
```

I am confused on assigning values below here

```
<p>
  Scoring:
  <select id="options">
    <option value="3">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="7">3</option>
    <option value="6">4</option>
    <option value="8">5</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" id="findScore" value="Score" onclick="return scoringValue()" />
  Total Points: <input type="text" id="totalPoints" value=0 disabled="disabled" class="output" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `parseInt` values in your code, because they exists as string. So if you will sum two strings "2" + "2", the result will be "22". So the answer is: use `parseInt` to transform the string to a number to sum them properly. Here is an example:

```js
function scoringValue() {
  var chosenOne = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalPoints").value, 10) + 
  parseInt(document.getElementById("options").value, 10);
  document.getElementById("totalPoints").value = chosenOne;
}
```

```html
<p>Scoring:<select id="options">
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="findScore" value="Score" onclick="scoringValue()" />
      Total Points: <input type="text" id="totalPoints" value=0 
      disabled="disabled" class="output" />
```

Comment: please note that you should always include the RADIX parameter when calling `parseInt`, in this case `parseInt(item.value, 10)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: @Steve, yes, thank you, it's a good practice. But in this case it doesn't matter. But I've updated the answer as you recommended, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert you values from string to int and then perform your calculation.

Example:

```
function scoringValue() {
    var totalPoints = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalPoints").value, 10);
    var optionsValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("options").value, 10);
    var chosenOne =  totalPoints + optionsValue;
    document.getElementById("totalPoints").value = chosenOne;
}
```